# How to generate a random unique string with more than 2^30 combination. I also wanted to reverse the process. Is this possible?

Tags: java, security, random, checksum, xor

I have a string which contains 3 elements:

- a 3 digit code (example: SIN, ABD, SMS, etc)
- a 1 digit code type (example: 1, 2, 3, etc)
- a 3 digit number (example: 500, 123, 345)

Example string: SIN1500, ABD2123, SMS3345, etc..

I wanted to generate a UNIQUE 10 digit alphanumeric and case sensitive string (only 0-9/a-z/A-Z is allowed), with more than 2^30 (about 1 billion) unique combination per string supplied. The generated code must have a particular algorithm so that I can reverse the process. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "ABD2123";
    String result = generateData(test);
    System.out.println(generateOutput(test)); //for example, the output of this is: 1jS8g4GDn0
    System.out.println(generateOutput(result)); //the output of this will be ABD2123 (the original string supplied)
}
```

What I wanted to ask is is there any ideas/examples/libraries in java that can do this? Or at least any hint on what keyword should I put on Google?

I tried googling using the keyword java checksum, rng, security, random number, etc and also tried looking at some random number solution (java SecureRandom, xorshift RNG, java.util.zip's checksum, etc) but I can't seem to find one?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

My use case for this program is to generate some kind of unique voucher number to be used by specific customers.

The string supplied will contains 3 digit code for company ID, 1 digit code for voucher type, and a 3 digit number for the voucher nominal. I also tried adding 3 random alphanumeric (so the final digit is 7 + 3 digit = 10 digit). This is what I've done so far, but the result is not very good (only about 100 thousand combination):

```
public static String in ="somerandomstrings";
public static String out="someotherrandomstrings";

public static String encrypt(String kata)
throws Exception {
    String result="";
    String ina=in;
    String outa=out;
    Random ran = new Random();
    Integer modulus=in.length();
    Integer offset= ((Integer.parseInt(Utils.convertDateToString(new Date(), "SS")))+ran.nextInt(60))/2%modulus;

    result=ina.substring(offset, offset+1);
    ina=ina+ina;
    ina=ina.substring(offset, offset+modulus);
    result=result+translate(kata, ina, outa);

    return result;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I'm sorry I forgot to put the "translate" function :

```
    public static String translate(String kata,String  seq1, String  seq2){
    String result="";
    if(kata!=null&seq1!=null&seq2!=null){
        String[] a=kata.split("");
        for (int j = 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            String b=a[j];                      
            String[]seq1split=seq1.split("");
            String[]seq2split=seq2.split("");
            int hint=seq1.indexOf(b)+1;

            String sq="";
            if(seq1split.length>hint)
                sq=seq1split[hint];
            String sq1="";
            if(seq2split.length>hint)
                sq1=seq2split[hint];

            b=b.replace(sq, sq1);

            result=result+b;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Okay, after a few days I'm currently struggling to convert the Ruby code provided by @sarnold, this is the code I've come up with :

```
public class Test {

static char START_A = "A".charAt(0);
static char START_a = "a".charAt(0);
static char START_0 = "0".charAt(0);
static int CODEMASK = ((1 << 28) - 1); //turn on lower 28 bits
static int RANDOMMASK = ((1 << 60) - 1) & ~ CODEMASK; //turn on upper 32 bits

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] test = new String[]{
            //"AAA0000", "SIN1500", "ABD2123", "SMS3345", "ZZZ9999",
            //"ABD2123", "ABD2123", "ABD2123", "ABD2123", "ABD2123"
            "ABD2123"
            };

    for(String t : test){
        long c = compress(t);
        long a = add_random(c);
        String output = to_output(a);
        long input = from_output(output);

        String[] new_c_r = remove_random(input);
        String u = uncompress(Long.valueOf(new_c_r[0]));

        System.out.println("Original input: " + t);
        System.out.println("    compressed: " + c);
        System.out.println("    after adding random amount: " + a);
        System.out.println("    *output: " + output);
        System.out.println("    *input: " + input);
        System.out.println("    random amount added: " + new_c_r[1]);
        System.out.println("    after removing random amount: " + new_c_r[0]);
        System.out.println("    uncompressed: " + u);
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
    }

}

public static long compress(String line){ //7 character
    char a = line.charAt(0);
    char b = line.charAt(1);
    char c = line.charAt(2);
    char h = line.charAt(3);
    char i = line.charAt(4);
    char j = line.charAt(5);
    char k = line.charAt(6);

    long small_a = (long) a - START_A;
    long small_b = (long) b - START_A;
    long small_c = (long) c - START_A;
    long letters = (small_a * 26 * 26) + (small_b * 26) + small_c;
    long numbers = letters * 10000 + h * 1000 + i*100 + j*10 + k;
    return numbers;
}

public static String uncompress(long number){
    long k = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
    long j = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
    long i = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
    long h = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
    long small_c = number % 26;
    number /= 26;
    long small_b = number % 26;
    number /= 26;
    long small_a = number % 26;
    number /= 26;

    if (number != 0) throw new RuntimeException("input wasn't generated with compress()");

    long a = small_a + START_A;
    long b = small_b + START_A;
    long c = small_c + START_A;

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    result.append((char) a).append((char) b).append((char) c).append(h).append(i).append(j).append(k);

    return result.toString();
}

public static long add_random(long number){
    return (((long) (Math.random()* Math.pow(2, 31))) << 28) + number;
}

public static String[] remove_random(long number){
    return new String[]{String.valueOf(number & CODEMASK), String.valueOf(number & RANDOMMASK)};
}

public static String to_output(long number){
    List<Character> a = new ArrayList<Character>();
    do{
        a.add(transform_out(number % 62));
        number /= 62;
    }while(number > 0);

    Collections.reverse(a);

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++){
        Character s = (Character) a.get(i);
        result.append(s);
    }

    return result.toString();
}

public static long from_output(String string){
    long num = 0;
    for(char c : string.toCharArray()){
        num *= 62;
        num += transform_in(c);
    }
    return num;
}

public static char transform_out(long small){
    long out;

    if (small < 0 || small > 61){
        throw new RuntimeException("small should be between 0 and 61, inclusive");
    }
    if(small < 26){
        out = START_A + small;
    }else if(small < 52){
        out = START_a + (small-26);
    }else{
        out = START_0 + (small-52);
    }
    return (char) out;
}


public static long transform_in(char c){
    if(!String.valueOf(c).matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]")){ 
        throw new RuntimeException("char should be A-Z, a-z, or 0-9, inclusive");
    }
    long num = (long) c;

    long out;
    if(num >= START_A && num <= START_A+26) out = num-START_A;
    else if(num >= START_a && num <= START_a+26) out = (num-START_a) + 26;
    else if(num >= START_0 && num <= START_0+10) out = (num-START_0) + 52;
    else throw new RuntimeException("Salah, bego!");

    return out;
}}
```

but I can't seem to make this code right, the result is like this :

```
Original input: ABD2123
compressed: 345451
after adding random amount: 62781252268541291
*output: EnhZJdRFaj
*input: 62781252268541291
random amount added: 0
after removing random amount: 345451
uncompressed: ABI5451
```

as you've probably noticed the "compressed" and the "uncompressed" field didn't show the same amount. The "random amount added" field is also always returning 0 value.
Is there anyone who can help see where I'm wrong in this code?

I'm sorry if it's a mistake to put this code in this thread I will create another thread.

Thank You,
Yusuf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a Ruby tool that does what you need. (Sorry it isn't Java, but my Java is over a decade old by now. But the general idea should port to Java without hassle.)

In short, the given input string (7 bytes) is compressed into a number between `0` and `175_760_000` (28 bits). A 32 bit random number is prepended, making a 60 bit integer, which is encoded into a 10-character output string.

My earlier math was wrong; since your input is only 28 bits long and your desired output is 60 bits long, that leaves 32 bits for adding roughly two billion random permutations. I mistyped when performing my calculations.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
START_A = "A"[0]
START_a = "a"[0]
START_0 = "0"[0]
CODEMASK = ((1 << 28) - 1) # turn on lower 28 bits
RANDOMMASK = ((1 << 60) - 1) & ~ CODEMASK # turn on upper 32 bits


def compress(line)
    a, b, c, h, i, j, k = line.chomp().each_char().entries()
    a, b, c = a[0], b[0], c[0]
    small_a, small_b, small_c = a - START_A, b - START_A, c - START_A
    letters = (small_a * 26**2) + (small_b * 26) + small_c
    h, i, j, k = Integer(h), Integer(i), Integer(j), Integer(k)
    number = letters * 10_000 + h*1000 + i*100 + j*10 + k
end

def uncompress(number)
    k = number % 10
    number /= 10
    j = number % 10
    number /= 10
    i = number % 10
    number /= 10
    h = number % 10
    number /= 10
    small_c = number % 26
    number /= 26
    small_b = number % 26
    number /= 26
    small_a = number % 26
    number /= 26
    if (number != 0)
            raise "input wasn't generated with compress()"
    end
    a, b, c = small_a + START_A, small_b + START_A, small_c + START_A
    [a.chr(), b.chr(), c.chr(), h.to_s(), i.to_s(), j.to_s(), k.to_s()].join()
end

def add_random(number)
    (rand(2**31) << 28) + number
end 

def remove_random(number)
    [number & CODEMASK, number & RANDOMMASK]
end

def to_output(number)
    a = []
    begin
            a << transform_out(number % 62)
            number /= 62
    end while(number > 0)
    a.reverse().join()
end

def from_output(string)
    num = 0
    string.each_char() do |c|
            num *= 62
            num += transform_in(c)
    end     
    num
end

def transform_out(small)
    if (small < 0 || small > 61)
            raise "small should be between 0 and 61, inclusive"
    end
    if (small < 26)
            out = START_A+small
    elsif (small < 52)
            out = START_a+(small-26)
    else
            out = START_0+(small-52)
    end
    out.chr()
end

def transform_in(char)
    if (/^[A-Za-z0-9]$/ !~ char)
            raise "char should be A-Z, a-z, or 0-9, inclusive"
    end
    num = char[0]
    out = case num
    when START_A .. START_A+26 then num - START_A
    when START_a .. START_a+26 then (num - START_a) + 26
    when START_0 .. START_0+10 then (num - START_0) + 52
    end

    out
end


begin
    while(line = DATA.readline()) do
            line.chomp!()
            c = compress(line)
            a = add_random(c)
            output = to_output(a)
            input = from_output(output)
            new_c, r = remove_random(input)
            u = uncompress(new_c)

            printf("original input: %s\n compressed: %d\n after adding random amount: %d\n *output: %s\n *input: %s\n random amount added: %d\n after removing random amount: %d\nuncompressed: %s\n", line, c, a, output, input, r, new_c, u)
    end
rescue EOFError => e
end


__END__
AAA0000
SIN1500
ABD2123
SMS3345
ZZZ9999
```

Running the program with the five inputs given at the bottom results in this output:

```
$ ./compress.rb
original input: AAA0000
 compressed: 0
 after adding random amount: 508360097408221184
 *output: liSQkzXL1G
 *input: 508360097408221184
 random amount added: 508360097408221184
 after removing random amount: 0
uncompressed: AAA0000
original input: SIN1500
 compressed: 123891500
 after adding random amount: 421470683267231532
 *output: fIVFtX9at2
 *input: 421470683267231532
 random amount added: 421470683143340032
 after removing random amount: 123891500
uncompressed: SIN1500
original input: ABD2123
 compressed: 292123
 after adding random amount: 414507907112269083
 *output: emb6JfDhUH
 *input: 414507907112269083
 random amount added: 414507907111976960
 after removing random amount: 292123
uncompressed: ABD2123
original input: SMS3345
 compressed: 124983345
 after adding random amount: 383242064398325809
 *output: cTPpccLAvn
 *input: 383242064398325809
 random amount added: 383242064273342464
 after removing random amount: 124983345
uncompressed: SMS3345
original input: ZZZ9999
 compressed: 175759999
 after adding random amount: 27149937199932031
 *output: CAVf14tiRh
 *input: 27149937199932031
 random amount added: 27149937024172032
 after removing random amount: 175759999
uncompressed: ZZZ9999
```

The lines you're really looking for are `original input`, `*output`, and `uncompressed`. Your client has the `original input` lines, after using the `to_output(add_random(compress(input)))` you will get the ten-character `A-Za-z0-9` output in the `*output` line. You hand that to users, and it's a magic token of some sort. Then when it is time to validate them, you use `remove_random(from_output(user_string))` to discover both the random value added to the string *and* an integer that you can hand to `uncompress()`.

One **very important note**: The input `AAA0000` is stored in plaintext in the lower 28 bits. The random number is stored in plaintext in the upper 32 bits. This is simply an *obfuscation* of the original inputs, it wouldn't be hard for someone to discover the pattern if they have two inputs and outputs. Heck, they might even correctly guess the algorithm given only a single input and output.

If you need this to be cryptographically strong, then you've still got some work ahead of you :) but that *might* be as easy as XORing the intermediate 60 bit number with rc4 output of the username or something like that.

**Short Explanation**

Your input strings can be interpreted as integers, but [with a twist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix): the first three 'digits' are in [base 26](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexavigesimal), the next four digits are in base 10. The number will be less than `175_760_000`. Uniquely storing numbers between `0` and `175_760_000` requires `28` bits. Your output strings are also a number, ten digits long, with each 'digit' in base 62. (Think [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) but without `-`, `/`, or `=` (for padding).) 62 possible values and ten positions gives you a maximum value of `839_299_365_868_340_224`, which can be represented in `60` bits.

The input string only takes `28` bits to represent, your output string has `60` bits available, and that leaves `32` bits available for storing a randomly-generated number. If we multiply a `32`-bit number by `2^28` (the same as a left-shift by 28: `1 << 28`) then the lower `28` bits will be free for the originally input number.

Once we've calculated the `60` bit number, we output it in our base 62 notation for human consumption.

To reverse the process, you decode the base 62 number to get our `60` bit number; split the `60` bit number into the lower `28` bit input number and upper `32` bit random number, and then output the `28` bit number in the original format: three base 26 digits followed by four base 10 digits.

**FINAL UPDATE**

Yusuf, excellent work converting my Ruby to Java. I'm very impressed, especially given how  *good* your Java version looks: your version is more legible. I'm jealous and impressed. :)

I found the two small bugs that remained in your program: `RANDOMMASK` was accidentally initialized to `0`, because Java [doesn't promote all operands into the final data type](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5121) when executing arithmetic shift statements. Changing `1` to `1L` forces the result of `1L << 60` to be a `long`; without the `L`, the result of `1 << 60` is an `int`, and isn't large enough to hold the full number.

Further, the digits weren't being compressed correctly; my Ruby code *parsed* the characters as an integer, and your Java code *interpreted* the characters as an integer. (Yours used the character's value; mine converted the character to an integer based on the ascii *meaning* of the character. Mine wasn't really *parsing*, since it is just doing a subtraction, but if it were a string, `String.toInteger(character)` would do the same thing, so it is a lot *like* parsing.)

But your uncompress logic was correct, and because of the mismatch, the output was incorrect. So I changed your code to parse the digits into integers (and changed from `char` to `int` to silence a pointless warning).

Here's a diff of what I had to change in your program to make it work:

```
--- Compress.java.orig  2011-03-25 16:57:47.000000000 -0700
+++ Compress.java   2011-03-25 17:09:42.000000000 -0700
@@ -1,12 +1,12 @@
-import java.util.*
+import java.util.*;

 public class Compress {

 static char START_A = "A".charAt(0);
 static char START_a = "a".charAt(0);
 static char START_0 = "0".charAt(0);
-static int CODEMASK = ((1 << 28) - 1); //turn on lower 28 bits
-static int RANDOMMASK = ((1 << 60) - 1) & ~ CODEMASK; //turn on upper 32 bits
+static long CODEMASK = ((1 << 28) - 1); //turn on lower 28 bits
+static long RANDOMMASK = ((1L << 60) - 1) & ~ CODEMASK; //turn on upper 32 bits

 public static void main(String[] args) {

@@ -42,10 +42,10 @@
     char a = line.charAt(0);
     char b = line.charAt(1);
     char c = line.charAt(2);
-    char h = line.charAt(3);
-    char i = line.charAt(4);
-    char j = line.charAt(5);
-    char k = line.charAt(6);
+    int h = line.charAt(3) - START_0;
+    int i = line.charAt(4) - START_0;
+    int j = line.charAt(5) - START_0;
+    int k = line.charAt(6) - START_0;

     long small_a = (long) a - START_A;
     long small_b = (long) b - START_A;
```

And now the full source, just in case that's easier :)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Compress {

static char START_A = "A".charAt(0);
static char START_a = "a".charAt(0);
static char START_0 = "0".charAt(0);
static long CODEMASK = ((1 << 28) - 1); //turn on lower 28 bits
static long RANDOMMASK = ((1L << 60) - 1) & ~ CODEMASK; //turn on upper 32 bits

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] test = new String[]{
            //"AAA0000", "SIN1500", "ABD2123", "SMS3345", "ZZZ9999",
            //"ABD2123", "ABD2123", "ABD2123", "ABD2123", "ABD2123"
            "ABD2123"
            };

    for(String t : test){
        long c = compress(t);
        long a = add_random(c);
        String output = to_output(a);
        long input = from_output(output);

        String[] new_c_r = remove_random(input);
        String u = uncompress(Long.valueOf(new_c_r[0]));

        System.out.println("Original input: " + t);
        System.out.println("    compressed: " + c);
        System.out.println("    after adding random amount: " + a);
        System.out.println("    *output: " + output);
        System.out.println("    *input: " + input);
        System.out.println("    random amount added: " + new_c_r[1]);
        System.out.println("    after removing random amount: " + new_c_r[0]);
        System.out.println("    uncompressed: " + u);
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
    }

}

public static long compress(String line){ //7 character
    char a = line.charAt(0);
    char b = line.charAt(1);
    char c = line.charAt(2);
    int h = line.charAt(3) - START_0;
    int i = line.charAt(4) - START_0;
    int j = line.charAt(5) - START_0;
    int k = line.charAt(6) - START_0;

    long small_a = (long) a - START_A;
    long small_b = (long) b - START_A;
    long small_c = (long) c - START_A;
    long letters = (small_a * 26 * 26) + (small_b * 26) + small_c;
    long numbers = letters * 10000 + h * 1000 + i*100 + j*10 + k;
    return numbers;
}

public static String uncompress(long number){
    long k = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
    long j = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
    long i = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
    long h = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
    long small_c = number % 26;
    number /= 26;
    long small_b = number % 26;
    number /= 26;
    long small_a = number % 26;
    number /= 26;

    if (number != 0) throw new RuntimeException("input wasn't generated with compress()");

    long a = small_a + START_A;
    long b = small_b + START_A;
    long c = small_c + START_A;

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    result.append((char) a).append((char) b).append((char) c).append(h).append(i).append(j).append(k);

    return result.toString();
}

public static long add_random(long number){
    return (((long) (Math.random()* Math.pow(2, 31))) << 28) + number;
}

public static String[] remove_random(long number){
    return new String[]{String.valueOf(number & CODEMASK), String.valueOf(number & RANDOMMASK)};
}

public static String to_output(long number){
    List<Character> a = new ArrayList<Character>();
    do{
        a.add(transform_out(number % 62));
        number /= 62;
    }while(number > 0);

    Collections.reverse(a);

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++){
        Character s = (Character) a.get(i);
        result.append(s);
    }

    return result.toString();
}

public static long from_output(String string){
    long num = 0;
    for(char c : string.toCharArray()){
        num *= 62;
        num += transform_in(c);
    }
    return num;
}

public static char transform_out(long small){
    long out;

    if (small < 0 || small > 61){
        throw new RuntimeException("small should be between 0 and 61, inclusive");
    }
    if(small < 26){
        out = START_A + small;
    }else if(small < 52){
        out = START_a + (small-26);
    }else{
        out = START_0 + (small-52);
    }
    return (char) out;
}


public static long transform_in(char c){
    if(!String.valueOf(c).matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]")){ 
        throw new RuntimeException("char should be A-Z, a-z, or 0-9, inclusive");
    }
    long num = (long) c;

    long out;
    if(num >= START_A && num <= START_A+26) out = num-START_A;
    else if(num >= START_a && num <= START_a+26) out = (num-START_a) + 26;
    else if(num >= START_0 && num <= START_0+10) out = (num-START_0) + 52;
    else throw new RuntimeException("Salah, bego!");

    return out;
}}
```

Comment: It is acceptable (2^29). Do you have a hint/suggestion/example on how to do this? My use case is that I am trying to create some kind of unique voucher number for a specific customer. Thanks

Comment: Actually, the number of random combinations is much less, as 7 digits are determined in advances "at least 7 digits company ID, type, and nominal amounts." This means only 26^3 are genuinely random and can be used for format a unique combination.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, I assume that in the end, the individual vouchers will bear no resemblance to the input number: compressing the original 175 million inputs into the most compact representation is the only way this is remotely achievable, which is why I assumed it. :)

Comment: @sarnold - compression is just a reversible transformation, and it is not at all hard to figure out what the reverse transformation is.  Indeed, applying a typical text compression algorithm to short string is likely to give you something that is similar to the original.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! I'll try to first understand this code and implement in Java. I will post updates. I'm sorry but to be frank I still don't understand about all the inputs from @sarnold, @Stephen C, and @Peter Lawrey

Comment: Yusuf S, I'll append a new attempt at a short explanation, let me know if it helps or not. :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort! I will understand this, please bear with me. For a few days I've been struggling to convert your code into java, and as you can see I've appended a new edit, but I can't seem to make it right. Is there anyone who can help? Thanks again.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your final edit! I can finally make it work. I know there's still a lot of homework to do, like making it somewhat cryptographically strong, and try to understand more about security.

Comment: @Yusuf S, my pleasure -- it was a fun problem to solve, and finding the last little two bits in your (excellent) translated code was fun bug-hunting.

Comment: @Yusuf S, To make it cryptographically strong, I suggest XORing the 60-bit intermediate number with 60 bits retrieved from `/dev/urandom`; store those 60 bits in your database. (`read(2)` 8 bytes from `/dev/urandom`, zero the top `4` bits, do the XOR, and store the mask in your database. Do the XOR again when decrypting.) Using a stream cipher such as [Salsa20](http://cr.yp.to/snuffle.html#specification) would be better, but might require more work; [BouncyCastle Java support](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/Salsa20Engine.html).

Comment: Reading through all the help and comments from you guys really makes me realize I don't understand a thing about security :| Thank you for the directions @sarnold!

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are very unclear.  So I'm going to restrict my answer to generalities:

There are functions called cryptographic hash functions that will map from an arbitrary sequence of bytes to a "hash", with the property that the probability of any two related inputs giving the same output is vanishingly small.  However, cryptographic hash functions are (by design) not reversible ... by design.

A mapping from one "space" of Strings to another that is reversible, can be implemented in two ways:

- You can generate arbitrary Strings as the mapped Strings, and use data structures such as a hash tables to store the forward and reverse mappings.
- You can use a cryptographic hash function to generate the mapped Strings, and use data structures such as a hash tables to store the reverse mappings.
- You can use a reversible function to transform between the original and mapped Strings.  This has the problem that the mapping is *likely* to be be easy to reverse engineer.

An example of the latter might be to turn the original String into bytes and then base64 encode it.  Or even more trivially, you could insert a random character between each character in the input string.  (Obviously, transformations like these can be reverse engineered in a few minutes ... given enough examples.  So one has to doubt the wisdom of this approach.)

Without better requirements, it is unclear which (if any) of these approaches is what you need.

Comment: I don't know if this is feasible in the first place. My client wanted me to make some kind of program that can generate a voucher number that is unique, 10 digit, only consisting of alphanumeric characters. That voucher number must be reversible and contains at least 7 digits company ID, type, and nominal amounts. I think I will try your latter suggestion first. Thank you

Comment: If 7 digits are fixed, this mean you only have three letter to play with. For tickets with the same 7 digits you can only have 26^3 (17,576) unique combinations.

Comment: @Yusuf S - you need to ask your client whether he/she cares if the voucher numbers are guessable.  @Peter's point is that with only 3 characters to play with, they will **inevitably** be guessable if they are also reversible.  But the real issue is that **you** have to understand all of this so that you can articulate to the customer what the consequences of his requirements are.

Comment: I think the customer wanted it to be not guessable, but they also stated that it don't have to be cryptographically strong, because the voucher number is not used for anything crucial. Really thanks for all the replies, I will try to understand inputs from all of you since I'm relatively new at this.