# Why hashing functions like sha1 use only up to 16 different char (hexadecimal)?

Tags: php, encryption, sha1

Sorry for this curiosity that I have.

sha1 use `[a-f0-9]`  chars for its hashing function. May I know why it doens't use all the chars possible `[a-z0-9]` by using all chars availabe it could grealty increase the number of possibile different hash, thus lowering the probabilty of possibile collision.

If you don't think this is a real question, just leave a comment I will instantly delete this question.

===

As stated in the answer, sha1 does `NOT` uses only `16 chars`. The correct fact is: sha1 is 160 bits of binary data (cit.). I have added this to prevent confusion.

Comment: why downvote? It is a much clever question than many others!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're confusing *representation* with *content*.

sha1 *is* 160 bits of binary data. You can just as easily represent it with:

```
hex: 0xf1d2d2f924e986ac86fdf7b36c94bcdf32beec15
decimal: 1380568310619656533693587816107765069100751973397
binary: 1111000111010010110100101111100100100100111010011000011010101100100001101111110111110111101100110110110010010100101111001101111100110010101111101110110000010101
base 62: xufK3qj2bZgDrLA0XN0cLv1jZXc
```

There's nothing magical about hexidecimal. It's just very common mechanism for showing content that breaks easily along 4-bit boundaries.

The `base 62` output is generated with this little bit of ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

def chars_from_hex(s)
  c = s % 62
  s = s / 62
  if ( s > 0 )
    chars_from_hex(s)
  end
  if (c < 10)
      print c
  elsif (c < 36)
      print "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[c-11].chr()
  elsif (c < 62)
      print "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[c-37].chr()
  else
      puts "error c", c
  end
end

chars_from_hex(0xf1d2d2f924e986ac86fdf7b36c94bcdf32beec15)
```

It uses the standard idiom for [converting from one base to another](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Base_conversion) and treats `0-9` as 0-9, `a-z` as 10-35, `A-Z` as 36-61. It could be trivially extended to support more digits by including e.g. `` !@#$%^&*()-_=+\|[]{},.<>/?;:'"~` `` if one so desired. (Or any of the vast array of [Unicode codepoints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).)

@yes123 asked about the *ascii representation of the hash* specifically, so here is the result of interpreting the 160-bit hash directly as ascii:

```
ñÒÒù$é¬ý÷³l¼ß2¾ì
```

It doesn't look like much because:

- ascii doesn't have a good printable representation for byte values less than 32
- ascii itself can't represent byte values greater than 127, between 127 and 255 gets interpreted according to [iso-8859-01](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) or other [character encoding schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)

This base conversion can be practically useful, too; the [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding method uses 64 (instead of my 62) characters to represent 6 bits at a time; it needs two more characters for 'digits' and a character for padding. [UUEncoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencode) chose a different set of 'digits'. And [a fellow stacker had a problem that was easily solved by changing the base of input numbers to output numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293967/how-to-generate-a-random-unique-string-with-more-than-230-combination-i-also-wa/5294030#5294030).

Comment: @yes123 That's what you do when you convert from binary to an decimal ascii string. A byte with the value 0x5a becomes the ascii string "165" (which is 3 bytes with the values 0x31,0x36,0x35 , no information is lost).

Comment: @yes123 that binary string shown is its ascii representation.

Comment: The 11110... you see , in this answer, after the `binary: ` is its string representation. All the `hex: decimal: binary` values you see here is a string, in ascii that represents the exact same sha-1 hash

Comment: @lyke: i mean the rapresentation with chars and letters (and maybe strange chars)

Comment: @yes123 We can't represent the binary values on a web page or screen. There's no reasonable character set or font that allows that in any meaningful way. Thus when we want humans to visually read binary values, we usually convert them in 2 ways. To a suitable base, such as binary, decimal, hex. and we convert them to a character set (or a string if you like) that display devices can handle, which is usually ascii.

Comment: @lyke, excellent explanations, thanks. @yes123, I've updated my answer to include directly interpreting the 160-bit hash as ASCII output and a small ruby program to convert arbitrary integer input into a base-62 output, for representation in `0-9`, `a-z`, and `A-Z`.

Comment: @sarnold: gosh! your base64 owns. with that I guess we can save a lot of spaces in our db instead to storing a 40chars long string for sha1 we could just use 27 chars. Don't you think it's useful?

Comment: @yes123, you could store the 160 bits as 20 bytes (160 bits / (8 bits / byte)) in your database directly and save another 7 or 8 bytes per hash. But people are used to hexadecimal output for their hashes and probably want to _search_ using the hex form. You could convert to and from this format so you could support searching, but it seems like a lot of extra work to save 13 bytes per SHA-1 record. :)

Comment: @sarnold: "searching" sha1 hashes doens't seem a real way imo. if it's used is for directly access (example password hashed stored of course)

Comment: gosh the base 62 is so cool! i wonder why did they use just a-f0-9!

Comment: @yes123, probably several reasons: base62 requires an integer `modulo` operation _and_ integer `divide` operation, both of which are typically far more expensive than integer `shift` operations which would be used in preparing standard hexadecimal output; also, the hexadecimal format mirrors the internal binary state of the machine _very_ well. It's great for programmers, maybe less so for usual humans. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is false reasoning. sha1 uses 40*4=160 bits.

It just happens to be convenient (and therefore, the convention) to format that as 40 hex digits.

You can use different cryptographic hashes with a larger hash size, if you feel you are in a problem domain where collisions start to be likely in 160 bits

```
 sha224: 224 bits
 sha256: 256 bits
 md5: 128 bits
```

Comment: SHA1 uses 160 bits (or 20 bytes, or 40 hexadecimal digits).

Answer (score 2):

Using hex just allows for easier display. SHA1 uses 160 bits. By hex encoding it, it allows the digest to be easily displayed and transported as a string. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

The output of the hash algorithm is bits. Representing them in hex is just a representation. It does benefit from a result being of length 0 mod 16, so representation in base 17 would be inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

sha-1 produces a 160 bit hash, that's 20 bytes, which has 1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542976 possible values. Because that's how the hash algorithm is defined.

However, it's often useful encode that hash as readable text, and a convenient way is to simply encode those 20 bytes as hex(which will take up 40 bytes). And hex characters are [a-f0-9].